# Python hyphenated module "No module named foo-bar"

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a hyphenated module, I know Python isn't supposed to have dashes in module names, but this still should work. I have an `__init__.py` file in `foo-bar` with read permissions allowed for all users.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

['/home/mikob/workspace/foo-bar', ... ]

__import__('foo-bar')
ImportError: No module named foo-bar
```

Comment: `sys.path` should be `/home/../workspace/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sys.path` should be `/home/.../workspace/`

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to import a module named `foo-bar`, but you won't be able to do anything with it. Try running

```
foo-bar.some_method()
```

and you'll just get an error, as Python will think you're trying to subtract the value returned from `bar.some_method()` from a variable named `foo`. Since (one would assume) neither one of these exists, you'll get a `NameError: name 'foo' is not defined`.

There's a simple fix - follow Python's naming conventions and only use letters, digits, and underscores in your identifiers.